# Prevent CComboBox edit control from changing list selection

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a custom MFC `CComboBox` derivative, and whenever a user selects an item from the dropdown list, I want it to append the selection to the contents of the combo's edit control, instead of replacing it outright, as is the default combo box behaviour. I have the append bit working, but only for the first item in the list. I'm using `CEdit::ReplaceSel` to perform the text appending, but this alters the selection in the list, because (I think) it sends a notification to the edit control's parent (the combo) which then nullifies the selection the user made.

I've tried catching different messages that the edit control might send to the parent to trigger the selection reset, like `EN_CHANGE`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can probably post a message of your own to the combo box to update the edit control.  That will then kick in after the combo box has done its thing, although you will get a bit of screen flash.  I do something similar; it's fiddly to get right and hard to debug.

Comment: I would probably just remove the Edit field from the ComboBox and use a separate Edit control instead. That way, I would have more control over how the two interact with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Ditching the combo box altogether and using a separate edit control and list box  is something I've considered. I thought about custom messages too, but I couldn't figure out a way to update the edit control that doesn't also notify the postbox and wipe the current selection.

Comment: You could sub-class the combo and stop it receiving the `EN_CHANGE` notification while the edit control is processing your `EM_REPLACESEL` message.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonathanPotter. In the end I did what you suggested and subclassed the combo box's window procedure  except in my case I discarded WM_SETTEXT messages that I didn't send myself, rather than EN_CHANGE. It seems SetWindowText on a combo triggers a huge cascade of messages that ultimately end in WM_SETTEXT. Honestly one of the most baffling projects I've ever worked on but I learned a lot along the way :)